# Reduce an array into an object in MondoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have an object of type

```
{
  venue: 'La Rocca'
  shifts: [
    { type: 'Morning', employee: 'Jake Sullivan' },
    { type: 'Morning', employee: 'Paul Smith' },
    { type: 'Evening', employee: 'Mike Sullivan' },
    { type: 'Morning', employee: 'Mike Belloney' },
  ]
}
```

I want to use `$reduce` to create a property as such:

```
{
  counts: {
    morning: 3,
    evening: 1,
  },
}
```

Can this be done by avoiding `$unwind` and `$group`? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         counts: {
            $reduce: {
               input: { $setUnion: "$shifts.type" },
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: ["$$value",
                     [{
                        k: "$$this",
                        v: {
                           $size: {
                              $filter: {
                                 input: "$shifts",
                                 as: "item",
                                 cond: { $eq: ["$$item.type", "$$this"] }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         counts: { $arrayToObject: "$counts" }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S4pgiR9oWHX)